# Writing from a list to a text file C#

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I code the whole list into the text file with commas in between each bit of data? Currently it is creating the file newData, but it is not putting in the variables from the list. Here is what I have so far.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
  List<string> newData = new List<string>();
}
```

Above is where I create my list. Below is where I am reading it from.

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("NewData.txt");
  tw.WriteLine(newData);
  buttonSave.Enabled = true;
  textBoxLatitude.Enabled = false;
  textBoxLongtitude.Enabled = false;
  textBoxElevation.Enabled = false;
}
```

And below is where the variables are coming from.

```
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  newData.Add (textBoxLatitude.Text);
  newData.Add (textBoxLongtitude.Text);
  newData.Add (textBoxElevation.Text);
  textBoxLatitude.Text = null;
  textBoxLongtitude.Text = null;
  textBoxElevation.Text = null;
}
```

Comment: What happens when someone enters 1,000 for elevation?  This file then makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("NewData.txt");                       
        tw.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", newData));

        // Add appropriate error detection
    }
```

In response to the discussion in both main answer threads, here is an example from my older code of a more robust way to handle CSV output:

The above not checked for syntax, but the key concept is `String.Join`.

```
 public const string Quote = "\"";

 public static void EmitCsvLine(TextWriter report, IList<string> values)
    {
        List<string> csv = new List<string>(values.Count);

        for (var z = 0; z < values.Count; z += 1)
        {
            csv.Add(Quote + values[z].Replace(Quote, Quote + Quote) + Quote);
        }

        string line = String.Join(",", csv);

        report.WriteLine(line);
    }
```

This could be made slightly more general with an `IEnumerable<object>` but in the code I took this form, I didn't have the need to.

Comment: Have you invoked close() on the TextWriter?

Comment: I indicated there was no error detection here--in production code, I would put the declaration of the TextWriter in a `using` statement.  However, when the TextWriter object is cleaned up (at program end if not earlier by the GC), the `Close` method will be called automatically.

Comment: This method fails to produce a file that can be parsed on return when the elevation is input as "1,000" (or for anything where the thousands separator is entered).  The user input needs to be constrained more or the input has to be sanitized in order for this to work.

Comment: That is true if there are commas in the input, yes.  Most computerized data not intended for humans doesn't have that, but if it does, a different separator would be required.  If the general case of any content is required, using one of many encoding schemes would be required.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Note that a) the input is coming from textboxes, and b) you're dealing with values that could very easily have commas in it (look at elevation).

Answer (score 5):

While you can use `String.Join` as others have mentioned they're ignoring three important things:

- The fact that what you're really trying to do is write a [comma-separated values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file
- The input that you're receiving and whether or not it will have commas in it
- If you sanitize your input, what the current culture on the thread is when you write it out to the file

You want to write a comma-delimited file. There's no standardized format for this, but you do have to be careful of string content, especially in *your* case, where you're getting user input.  Consider the following input:

```
latitude = "39,41"
longitude = "41,20"
```

There are a [number of countries where the comma is used as a decimal separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_comma), so this kind of input is very possible, depending on how distributed your application is (I'd be even more concerned if this was a website, personally).

And when getting the elevation, it's absolutely possible in most other places that use a comma as the thousands separator:

```
elevation = 20,000
```

In all of the other answers, your output for the line in the file will be:

```
39,41,41,20,20,000
```

Which when parsed (assuming it will be parsed, you're creating a machine-readable format) will fail.

What you want to do is *parse* the content first into a decimal and then output that.

Assuming you sanitize your input like so:

```
decimal latitude = Decimal.Parse(textBoxLatitude.Text);
decimal longitude = Decimal.Parse(textBoxLongitude.Text);
decimal elevation = Decimal.Parse(textBoxElevation.Text);
```

You would then format the values so that there are no commas (if you want).

To that end, I really recommend that you want to use a dedicated CSV writer/parser (try [ServiceStack's serializer on NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Text), or [others](http://nuget.org/packages?q=csv), if you prefer), which accounts for commas within the content you want separated by commas.

Comment: I like the fact that the most decent answer here is not the accepted answer. In fact, it would probably break at some point due to the commas in the user input and he'd be back with another question :P.

Comment: @KreepN Yeah, I was trying to see what the user really wanted, and turn it into a teaching moment.

Comment: So is the plight of posting in these sorts of questions, people post up the easiest answer and many times the answer itself doesn't follow best practices. The TextWriter implements IDisposable and should be wrapped in a Using statement, but the answer given leaves it out.

Comment: @KreepN Personally, I'd just point that out in a comment, or maybe even edit it.  In these sorts of questions, as you can see from the rest of the answers, people were trying to be *first* instead of being *correct*.  It's proof that votes are not necessarily a sign of how *correct* an answer is (although it does, usually).  However, to be fair, it's a simple problem that *could* have larger issues, which is what I tried to point out (and prefer to do).  That doesn't mean that the accepted answer is *wrong* necessarily, just that it's concise.

Comment: @KreepN Although I do believe it to be wrong because it neglects to point out the issues that I raise above, which I think are directly tied to the user's question, given that he's working with coordinate systems *and* elevation, both of which can have commas embedded in the values depending on locale and the range of the values.

Comment: That's why I said "decent answer" and did not criticize the fact that his answer did get the desired result (for now). It was mentioned in his comments, but for future users that may just copy the answer, it's going to get missed. Anywho, I appreciate your answer as I learned from it and have never seen the dedicated parsers you mentioned.

Comment: @KreepN No problem.  I have enough rep, so knowing I helped someone out or gain a deeper understanding in some way is always a good thing. =)

Comment: I wrote the first answer, answering what the OP asked.   In my own code library, I have a function called that encodes arbitrary lists as legal CSV for this very purpose.  But it isn't what was asked.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ It's what the OP asked, but that doesn't mean that those issues might not likely exist.  It's an obvious case where the OP hasn't considered the output given the inputs.  And you didn't post what was in *your* code library.

Comment: See updated answer in first thread--it includes some of my older code that does true proper CSV encoding, although that wasn't what was asked for.  And yes, I have learned to answer quick and simple.   I spent two hours chatting with a guy and teaching him good technique a couple days ago, and telling him why what he wanted was a bad idea.  This morning, I lost my 15 points for accepted answer when someone posted a quick work around to do the thing that he wanted to do despite its being a bad idea.  SO trains us to give quick, focused answers, not to educate.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I won't debate that SO trains and rewards the quick, easy answer, but to be honest, we can do better than that.  I'm not saying your answer was wrong, but there was a swath of information left out that could easily be deduced from the question.  Don't let FGITW seduce you into not giving the best answer you can give the *first* time.

Comment: @casperOne Frankly, the first time I didn't notice he was doing CSV--I thought he didn't understand String.Join.   I had the code all along, as you can now see.

Answer (score 0):

```
You cannot output the list just by calling tw.WriteLine(newData);
```

But something like this will achieve that:

```
tw.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", newData));
```

Answer (score -1):

you could:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string s in yourList)
{
    b.Append(s);
            b.Append(", ");
}

string dir = "c:\mypath";
File.WriteAllText(dir, b.ToString());
```

Comment: This will leave an extra comma at the end, as written.

Answer (score -1):

You have to iterate the List (not tested) or use string.Join, as the other users suggested (you need to convert your list to an array then)

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("NewData.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < newData.Count; i++) 
        {                   
           tw.Write(newData[i]);
           if(i < newData.Count-1)
           { 
              tw.Write(",");
           }
        }
        tw.close();
        buttonSave.Enabled = true;
        textBoxLatitude.Enabled = false;
        textBoxLongtitude.Enabled = false;
        textBoxElevation.Enabled = false;

    }
```