# How Can I Use FileStream in C# to Make File with List<>?

Tags: c#, filestream

I Want Write File In C#. and Data Type, to Write is List<> But I Can't Use FileStream.
If I Made a File to Use FileStream, That File is Empty,

so, I Want Ask, How Can I Use FileStream to Write List<>???? T_T

Comment: Pls try editing your question i dont understand. Do you want to read from a file and store in a list or store a list in a file??

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it's unclear what you're trying, or how it's failing.

But this example might help:

[Writing from a list to a text file C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611202/writing-from-a-list-to-a-text-file-c-sharp)

```
List<string> newData = new List<string>();
...

private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  newData.Add (textBoxLatitude.Text);
  newData.Add (textBoxLongtitude.Text);
  newData.Add (textBoxElevation.Text);
  ...

private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("NewData.txt");                       
  tw.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", newData));
  ...
```

You can also iterate through your list, writing one item at a time.